# Convert a list of strings to a list of maps using Java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of strings in the following pattern

```
String test ="name=john,age=28;name=paul,age=30;name=adam,age=50";
List<String> listOfStrings = Arrays.asList(test.split(";"));
```

I want to convert the above list of strings to a list of map of key value pairs (like shown below).

```
[{name=john, age=28}, {name=paul, age=30}, {name=adam, age=50}]
```

Each entry in the above list a map with keys as name and age and values as their corresponding values.

This is what I have done to achieve the result.

```
listOfStrings.stream()
  .map(record -> Arrays.asList(record.split(",")).stream().map(field -> field.split("="))
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(keyValue -> keyValue[0].trim(), keyValue -> keyValue[1].trim())))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I would like to know if that is efficient or if there is a better way to do it using Java streams.

Comment: When you really do `Arrays.asList(test.split(";"));` there is no point of using Java streams, its all in memory already and you can iterate the array and build a map manually

Comment: why would you use a map for this? a map implies a key, an age is not a key. further more, why using age? why not using a birthDate?

Comment: @Stultuske, I meant to say that the string `name` would be a key and the string `age` would another key.

Comment: @Ravi sounds like you don't know what a key is, or how it works. one value is a key (has to be unique, neither name nor age would be unique) the other is 'value'

Comment: @user39950 Even when completely in-memory is often easier and more readable to write `Stream` code than explicit loops. For one: an explicit loop can potentially do *anything*, which means it can also contain any kind of bug. `Stream` operations are well-known and well defined, so by looking at the operations you already have a very good idea at what is happening. With a loop you have to look at the whole loop, decode every single line and ensure that nothing fancy happens, and only afterwards you have a good idea at what it does.

Comment: @Stultuske, take a look at the output `[{name=john, age=28}, {name=paul, age=30}, {name=adam, age=50}]`. The structure of my map is `Map<String, String>`. In the example taken, there would be three maps in total. So, I will insert the data into those three maps like this. `map1.put("name","john");map1.put("age","28");map2.put("name","paul");map2.put("age","30");map3.put("name","adam");map3.put("age","50");` I hope you understood my intention now.

Comment: @Ravi I have seen your output, that changes nothing. either your code should be able to handle different input, or it is pointless to write it.
again: neither of the data in there is guaranteed unique, meaning neither of those variables is good pick for a key.

Comment: @Stultuske How `"age"` and `"name"` are not good candidates for a key? Of course, it's better to extract a dedicated class that has `age` and `name` fields, but still - your line of reasoning escapes me.

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski do you believe there is just one "John Smith" in America? Do you believe that for every age, there is only one person in existence with that age? a key is meant to be able to uniquely link to a certain element. Neither name nor age are good choices for that

Comment: @Stultuske But keys are not `"John Smith"` nor `27` here - these would be obviously wrong, and these are values here. Keys are, literally, `"name"` and `"age"`.

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski, that is exactly what I have tried to explain Stultuske in my previous comments.

Comment: as to my understanding, the goal was to link the two values: "John Smith", 27.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question twice?

Comment: @Eugene, the requirement is slightly different in this question when compared to my previous question. In my earlier question, we would have an outer map with some key and an inner map as the value. Here, we just have a 'flat map' with key value pairs.

Comment: @Ravi my bad... reopened

Answer (score 4):

Here is another alternative using pattern matching, not as fast as a for loop but much faster than the original stream solution in my measurements.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test ="name=john,age=28;name=paul,age=30;name=adam,age=50";
    String patternString = "(name)=(\\w*),(age)=(\\d*)[;]?";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
    List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    while (matcher.find()) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
        map.put(matcher.group(3), matcher.group(4));
        list.add(map);
    }
}
```

A slight performance improvement could be had by not matching against the keys (name & age) and instead hardcoding them when creating the map elements.

Comment: Interesting approach using regex, but with the drawback (at least in your current version) that the keys have to be known. Any chance for a redesign, that it matches anything infront of the = and uses it as key?

Comment: @ifloop, yes you could for instance replace the key (age/name) with `(\\w*)` to match any word.

Comment: An even better approach would be to define the range of letters that are allowed in a key, for instance `=` shouldn't be allowed, like `[a-zA-Z0-9_]*`

Answer (score 1):

If you are out for performace, ditch the Stream API. Especially streams with substreams are really bad for writing highly performant applications.

Here is a comparison of your Stream API version vs. a plain old for-loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final String test = "name=john,age=28;name=paul,age=30;name=adam,age=50";

  final List<Map<String, String>> result1 = loop(test);
  final List<Map<String, String>> result2 = stream(test);

  System.out.println(result1);
  System.out.println(result2);
}


private static List<Map<String, String>> loop(String str) {
  long start = System.nanoTime();

  List<Map<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
  String[] persons = str.split(";");

  for (String person : persons) {
    String[] attributes = person.split(",");
    Map<String, String> attributeMapping = new HashMap<>();

    for (String attribute : attributes) {
      String[] attributeParts = attribute.split("=");

      attributeMapping.put(attributeParts[0], attributeParts[1]);
    }

    result.add(attributeMapping);
  }

  long end = System.nanoTime();
  System.out.printf("%d nano seconds\n", (end - start));

  return result;
}

private static List<Map<String, String>> stream(final String str) {
  long start = System.nanoTime();

  List<String> listOfStrings = Arrays.asList(str.split(";"));
  List<Map<String, String>> result = listOfStrings.stream()
    .map(record -> Arrays.asList(record.split(",")).stream().map(field -> field.split("="))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(keyValue -> keyValue[0].trim(), keyValue -> keyValue[1].trim())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

  long end = System.nanoTime();

  System.out.printf("%d nano seconds\n", (end - start));

  return result;
}
```

Outpout:

> 183887 nano seconds
>
> 53722108 nano seconds
>
> [{name=john, age=28}, {name=paul, age=30}, {name=adam, age=50}]
>
> [{name=john, age=28}, {name=paul, age=30}, {name=adam, age=50}]

Comment: thanks for putting the analysis. That's the reason why I have posted this question. I wanted to know if I have written an efficient solution or not.

Comment: Two points here: 1) I would be *very* careful about such benchmarking - until you benchmark this properly (see [Java Microbenchmar Harness](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)), it may turn out that the results are due to JVM not having warmed up properly, etc. 2) If you haven't recognized a performance bottleneck, prefer clarity/readability over performance. This is because you may lose more in future understanding/debugging such premature optimizations than save in response time.

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski fully agreed. 1) absolutely correct. This is just a quick and dirty measurement. Not claim for 100% correctness. But it gives a strong hint. 2) Using declarative style over functional style is not a premature optimization, it is a design decision. And in this case (Java + Stream API) it comes with the welcome side effect of beeing more efficient because of how complex the internals of the Stream API work.

Comment: Well, if you normally use functional style, and switch to declarative style for reasons of performance only, it is premature optimization. However, I agree that if you prefer declarative style (for various reasons, readability included), you should just go for it. We should *not* just try to write everything in a functional way because sometimes it just makes things less readable. That said, functional style (with proper formatting and refactored into methods, unlike in the question) is more readable to me here - it's simply much less verbose.

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski The switch to another paradigm could happen after days of discussion and extensive testing but only for the crucial parts that need the extra in performance. You may only change 2 functions with each 20 lines of code, but that is in no way premature just because it's different from the rest. Regarding you readability concerns: I agree, especially when talking maintainability. But coming from the efficiency side, I'd rather SEE the tripple nested for-loop (spidersense tangling) instead of the nicely aligned, not indented flatMap().flatMap().flatMap() which hides the complexity